# FPDF difficulties on creating multicell on array

Tags: php, fpdf

I need a help with FPDF how do I insert multi cell into my code?

```
  $data[] = array($row['item_qty'],
                    $row['itemname'],
                    number_format($row['item_price'],2),
                    number_format($row['total'],2),

             );
```

The data is too long I think, multicell is the best way but how can I transform it to multicell?

Comment: pls help me to fix my probmlem

Comment: this might help.. http://fpdf.org/en/script/script20.php

Comment: try this example http://www.freelancer.com/projects/PHP-Script-Install/Invoice-PDF-Using-PHP-fpdf.html

Comment: probably it helps a bit tnx:D